Show points from a GeoJSON timestamped map on Leaflet every 500 milliseconds
I need to use something like (remove layer when....) to show all the points that appear in a GeoJSON timestamped map every 500 milliseconds, and then erase them and show the next ones.
There are more than 30 thousand points. How can I do it? because the duration time in Leaflet is set to ISO8601 and it didn't work if I wrote PT0.5S for example.
I have tried also with folium but I have almost the same issue.
Here is my code...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet TimeDimension Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-timedimension@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.timedimension.control.min.css" />
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iso8601-js-period@0.2.1/iso8601.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-timedimension@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="archivo2.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Crear el mapa
        var map = L.map('map', {
            zoom: 18, maxZoom:30,
            center: [42.07898850603719,-8.63983380580476],
            zoomControl:true,
            timeDimension: true,
            timeDimensionOptions: {
                // timeInterval: "2024-09-30T14:50:41.972Z/2024-09-30T14:50:52.410Z",
                // period: "P1D"
            },
            timeDimensionControl: true,
            timeDimensionControlOptions: {
            
                playerOptions: { startOver: true },
                // autoPlay: true,
                // loopButton: true,
                // timeSliderDragUpdate: true,
                // speedSlider: true,
                // limitSliders: true
            }
        });
        // L.tileLayer('https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        //     maxZoom:22,
        //     attribution: 'Google'
        // }).addTo(map);
        L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/world_imagery/mapserver/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
            maxZoom: 30,
            attribution: 'Esri'
        }).addTo(map);

        var timedLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
            // style: function (feature) {
            //     return {
            //         color: 'green',
            //         weight: 2  // Doble del grosor predeterminado (2)
            //     };
            // },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                const color_value = feature.properties.style.color;
                return L.circle(latlng, {color:color_value, radius:1});
            },
            }), {
            updateCurrentTime: true,
            updateTimeDimension: true,
            updateTimeDimensionMode: 'replace',
            duration: "PT1S",
            addlastPoint: false
        });

        // Añadir la capa de datos al mapa
        timedLayer.addTo(map);
        L.FitOverlays().add_to(map)

        // Inicializar la animación en el punto de inicio
        var timeDimension = map.timeDimension;
        timeDimension.setCurrentTime(new Date("2023-07-20T00:00:00Z").getTime());

    </script>
</body>
</html>


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site. Stating that things "didn't work" without stating what you were trying and without describing what it did instead doesn't really leave much room for assistance. Please [Edit] the Question to explain how you are expecting the system for render 60000 points every second and report how long it takes to read each file.

@Vince As I understand, not all of the 30.000 points will be rendered every half a second, just the ones with time stamp that fall into specific interval of 0.5 second on the timeline. Problem is just how to set 0.5 second interval with ISO8601 syntax.

It seems you are out of luck here. iso8601-js-period@0.2.1 library does not support fractional seconds. But even if it did, it would not work with leaflet-timedimension@1.1.0 plugin, since it's internal logic is built on whole numbers for time units.

so, what can i do? Do you have any other idea to have a dinamical map with this information?

You could try this one: https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline. It has milliseconds resolution.
